# How to de-serialize Json to Map of Map?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to deserialize a json into

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>
```

This is the json structure that i want to convert.

```
{
     "filetype": {
        "cell": "value"
     },
     "fileType2": {
        "cell2": "value2"}
 }
```

I tried creating a class with `Map<String, Map<String, String>` type and tried  with `ObjectMapper(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper)` in jackson:

```
class MapOfMap {
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> mapOfMap;
    //getter and setter
}
```

```
objectMapper.readValue(
                new File(this.getClass()
                        .getClassLoader()
                        .getResource("configs/sample.json").getFile()),
                MapOfMap.class
        )
```

I am getting this error:

> Unrecognized field "fileType".

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please share the Jackson version. I used the 2.10.0 version and it worked well with Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = mapper.readValue(str, Map.class);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to write a wrapping class around your Map. Just tell the Mapper you want a Map:

```
    String jsonString = "{\n" + 
            "     \"filetype\": {\n" + 
            "        \"cell\": \"value\"\n" + 
            "     },\n" + 
            "     \"fileType2\": {\n" + 
            "        \"cell2\": \"value2\"}\n" + 
            " }";

    Map<String, Map<String, String>> map;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try {
        map = mapper.readValue(
            jsonString,
            new TypeReference<Map<String, Map<String, String>>>(){}
        );
        System.out.println(map);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It prints: `{filetype={cell=value}, fileType2={cell2=value2}}`, which looks like what you want.

For reference: [this](https://howtodoinjava.com/jackson/jackson-json-to-from-hashmap/)

Answer (score 1):

jackson

to Map

```
    public static HashMap<String,Object> jsonToMap(String json) throws IOException {
        JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);
        TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>> typeRef = new TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>>() {};
        return mapper.readValue(json, typeRef);
    }
```

to Object:

```
    public static <T> T jsonToObject(String json, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.readValue(json, clazz);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

using [gson](https://github.com/google/gson):

```
String json = "{\n" +
            "     \"filetype\": {\n" +
            "        \"cell\": \"value\"\n" +
            "     },\n" +
            "     \"fileType2\": {\n" +
            "        \"cell2\": \"value2\"\n" +
            "     }\n" +
            " }";
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Map map = gson.fromJson(json, Map.class); //will be a map of maps
```

note that gson defaults to LinkedTreeMaps (so the order of iteration of elements is preserved)